# Proper way to 'exit' a script in PHP

Tags: php

I have a static method named ServerResponse that basically shows a message whether on success or fail. I just want to know the proper way to actually display the message and exit the script.

Should I implement my method like this:

```
public static function ServerResponse($e,$m){

    print(json_encode([$e,$m]));
    exit;
}
```

//Sample use:

```
if(this happens){
    myclass::ServerResponse($x,$y);
}
```

or like this:

```
public static function ServerResponse($e,$m){
    return json_encode([$e,$m]);
}
```

//Sample use:

```
if(this happens){
    print(myclass::ServerResponse($x,$y));
    exit;
}
```

- Which one is proper and better... and why?
- is there any difference between them? (on execution time).

"Don't be hard on me I am not an expert (just yet)..."

Comment: You don't have to "manually" `exit` the script. It will end properly with or without `exit`, unless there's some weird reason why you want to stop execution immediately after the `ServerResponse` is emitted.

Comment: I am planning to use this with Ajax, so yes I have to actually terminate the script after the server has replied.

Comment: That's all OK, but if you're explicitly terminating the script using `exit`, after you printed out the JSON, that means there's further processing involved, like the script is doing something else after printing JSON. If that's the case, it's kind of a bad design, but yes - in that case you should terminate the script. And think about changing it so it just does one job.

Comment: Is there any defined proper way to actually implement an ajax response without actually executing the rest of the script? For instance, I send the request >> server responds >> then please ajax don't look at this, avoid that and until the script finishes on its own? If so, how?

Comment: There is - have a script that ONLY echoes that JSON. That way you don't have to use `exit` all over the place. This is why we use frameworks and MVC approach, so we can create small code that does one thing, and it does it well. From what you wrote so far, I don't think it's that easy to come up with MVC and drop it in to your script. You'd have to start all over again with the code.

Comment: I feel a bit frustrated you know. My scripts are full of exits all over them. I need to read about MVC and try to apply it. Anyway, thanks for your replies.

Comment: I believe you don't feel that great :) but using frameworks or certain concepts / data structures usually leads to less code that you need to write, thus less frustration. Yes, do read a bit about MVC, maybe try a small framework like `Silex` or a larger one like `Laravel`, you might end up doing things quicker with less code. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

For better debugging, it's advised to always make a function or method return a value. So your 2nd sample should be chosen.

`exit` (or `die`) are commonly used when the program ends with an error, giving the ability to add an exit status (as a number or a string).

I suppose there will be no significant difference about the execution time.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is common practice but I only use exit to debug. If your script comes to the end of execution it will exit on it's own.

If you must exit, do it in the main script, not in a function.
functions should have one task and do that task. So the function `ServerResponse` should send a response and not kill the script.

Comment: +1 for the comment about functions. Now, how do you deal with ajax requests then? If you don't exit the script, the rest of the script will continue executing.

Comment: I am guessing your question is really about routing your requests other than how to exit a script. Is it not?

Comment: Yes I guess. I have if else conditionals in my scripts that execute the requests if the request matches the condition. After that's done, well I exit the script otherwise I get an error. Everything works fine, but as a N.B. stated I guess its not the proper way.